# Apache Dynamic Virtual Host with Default Backup

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I've recently discovered the magic that is `VirtualDocumentRoot` in Apache configurations - but need a backfall for when the IP or root DNS is directly accessed.

The server is an EC2 instance running on AWS. Basically, I'd like to be able to handle dynamic domains and have a fallback if the instance is accessed directly. Here's what I've tried (which works for a specific domain, but not for the public DNS address):

```
# this is what ideally would serve non-domain requests
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/hosts/_generic
    ServerName amazonaws.com
    ServerAlias *.amazonaws.com
    ErrorLog logs/generic
</VirtualHost>

# serves dynamic hosts (example.com => /var/www/hosts/example.com)
# note: works as intended
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/hosts/%0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a case where I am interested in having a default DocumentRoot if the VirtualDocumentRoot is not available.  I ran across a post http://marc.info/?l=apache-httpd-dev&m=122264826010950&q=raw via http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html where source code was shared to provide this capability.  I wish I had more guidance.

> I've made a simple patch to mod_vhost_alias.  I've never done this 
>   before, so I'm probably going about it the wrong way, but here it is.
>
> Problem: mod_vhost_alias provides no ability to failover in the event 
>   that the transformed VirtualDocumentRoot does not exist.
>
> Solution: Check transformed VDR and return DECLINE if directory does
>   not  exist.  Then, httpd will default to the regular DocumentRoot (if
>   it was  defined alongside VirtualDocumentRoot).
>
> I'm not even sure if this behavior is considered "OK" - it's just what
>   I  needed and I grew a bit frustrated that it was not available.  It
>   might  be more prudent to put such a thing in a separate config option
>   in case  someone depends on the 404 that they get from a failed VDR 
>   transformation (I can't think of any situation that would require
>   this,  but who knows?)
>
> Here's my patch that implements this; it might be a bit dirty but it 
>   seems to work fine.  It does introduce an additional access() call per
>   request; I don't really see that as a problem but maybe someone else 
>   does.  (This patch is against the debian package source of 2.2.3;
>   again,  not sure if that's OK)
>
> ```
> --- mod_vhost_alias.c   2008-09-28 17:06:52.000000000 -0700
> +++ mod_vhost_alias_mine.c      2008-09-28 17:02:51.000000000 -0700
> @@ -37,7 +37,7 @@
>   #include "apr_strings.h"
>   #include "apr_hooks.h"
>   #include "apr_lib.h"
> -
> +#include <unistd.h>
>   #define APR_WANT_STRFUNC
>   #include "apr_want.h"
>
> @@ -250,7 +250,7 @@
>       }
>   }
>
> -static void vhost_alias_interpolate(request_rec *r, const char *name,
> +static int vhost_alias_interpolate(request_rec *r, const char *name,
>                                       const char *map, const char *uri)
>   {
>       /* 0..9 9..0 */
> @@ -372,12 +372,19 @@
>           ++uri;
>       }
>
> +    /* Check accessibility of transformed directory path */
> +    if(access(buf, R_OK)) {
> +        return 0;
> +    }
> +
>       if (r->filename) {
>           r->filename = apr_pstrcat(r->pool, r->filename, buf, uri, NULL);
>       }
>       else {
>           r->filename = apr_pstrcat(r->pool, buf, uri, NULL);
>       }
> +
> +    return 1;
>   }
>
>   static int mva_translate(request_rec *r)
> @@ -426,7 +433,8 @@
>        * canonical_path buffer.
>        */
>       r->canonical_filename = "";
> -    vhost_alias_interpolate(r, name, map, uri);
> +    if(!vhost_alias_interpolate(r, name, map, uri))
> +       return DECLINED;
>
>       if (cgi) {
>           /* see is_scriptaliased() in mod_cgi */
> ```